# Finding a string in a file and deleting all the text next to it in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following text in a file, and I would like to find the word `fox` and would like to delete the text from the word `fox` till the end of the text. (including `fox`)

```
The quick 
brown fox 
jumps over 
the lazy dog
```

I know the `/d` switch but it only deletes the line.

```
sed -i '/fox/d' file
```

The requested outcome will be:

```
The quick 
brown
```

Comment: Thanks, also the next text, I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed '/fox/{s/fox//;q;}' file
The quick
brown
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `sed` command,

```
sed '/fox/q' file | sed 's/fox//'
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat c
The quick 
brown  fox blah fox 
jumps over 
the lazy dog

$ sed '/fox/q' c | sed 's/fox.*//'
The quick 
brown
```

Comment: You'd better use `sed 's/fox.*//'` on the second `sed`, to delete the rest of the line where `fox` is found.

Comment: you're welcome! Note also that `/g` is not necessary, because it will happen just once.